# Question about the interpretation of boxplots in a chart

Tags: data-visualization, descriptive-statistics, odds-ratio

Can someone explain what these horizontal lines ( sort of boxplot?) against each condition represent? How is 1 a reference point? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please give more context.

Comment: As these are _not_ boxplots, please edit the title accordingly. Otherwise the title is a distraction for anyone who is interested in box plots. Interpretation of "point and interval displays" might be a better title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe you are looking at are a series of confidence intervals (likely 95%) on odds ratios (OR).
From [StatPearls](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK431098/#:%7E:text=Odds%20Ratio%20Confidence%20Interval&text=In%20order%20to%20calculate%20the,overall%20population%20is%20within%20range.), odds ratio is defined as

> a measure of how strongly an event is associated with exposure.

This is given by the odds of the eventin the exposed group divided by the odds of the event in the non-exposed group. In this figure, the authors compare the odds of ICU admission for several medical conditions. They calculated this by looking at the odds a patient is admitted to the ICU with, for example, an active cancer versus the odds a patient is admitted to the ICU without active cancer. If the odds of being admitted to the ICU with active cancer was equal to the odds of being admitted to the ICU without active cancer, then the odds ratio would be equal to 1.

By itself, however, this is insufficient. The authors go on to calculate confidence intervals of these ORs. With the confidence intervals, the authors can state with 95% confidence that the true OR is between some limits. If both limits are above 1,  or both are below 1, they can be 95% confident that this condition is associated with/against ICU stay in their study population.